# How do I split/sample from a cursor in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, batch-processing, sample

I have a database with millions of documents.  I want to perform a relatively time-consuming operation on each document and then update it.  I have two (related) questions:

1. If I want a random sample of, say, 1000 documents from a given cursor, how do I do that?
2. I want to compute on and update a million documents. I am on a cluster and I want to dispatch a separate job for each batch of, say 1000 documents.  What's the easiest way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Uri

Comment: 1. Unfortunately, the standard cursor api does not offer random sampling so you have to do it on the application side.

2. Can you give us more details on what you wanted to do? Depending on what you need, you might want to check findAndModify, mapreduce or the aggregation framework.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you'd have to push things to a worker manager. I would suggest gearman for this. In that case, a script would: 1. query all documents that you want to update, and return their _id. 2. push all object IDs into a gearman server 3. have a gearman worker process running on each of the machines in your cluster 4. have each gearman worker pick up a new object ID from the queue and process the document, saving it back into MonogDB.